# socket.io sending N messages when joining room N times

Tags: javascript, socket.io

When I join a room, and send a message, it sends only once, but if I leave the room and rejoin the same room, it sends the same message twice. The message gets duplicated the number of times i leave/join the room. I am properly leaving the room because I no longer receive messages when i have left the room.

```
io.on('connect', socket => {
  console.log('New client connected')

  socket.on('removeRoom', room => {
    socket.leave(room)
    socket.to(room).emit(room + '-newMessage', 'user has left room')
  })

  socket.on('joinRoom', room => {
    socket.join(room)

    socket.on(room + '-newMessage', data => {
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('recieveMessage', data)
    })
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving the room does not unregister the callback for the messages, it merely prevents the callback from being fired. When you re-join the room another callback is registered resulting in N messages being sent.

The easiest solution would be to remove the "newMessage" listener on "removeRoom".

```
socket.on('removeRoom', room => {
  socket.leave(room)
  socket.removeAllListeners(room + '-newMessage');
  socket.to(room).emit(room + '-newMessage', 'user has left room')
})
```

Comment: thank you!!! that was it! now since i didn't see removeAllListeners anywhere in tutorials when leaving rooms, what do you think would be a better approach for this, since i still want access to the room variable, where should i put the event handler?
or should i just leave it as is with the removeAllListeners ?

Comment: Unless you can register the "newMessage" callbacks at connection time (e.g. you know all of the rooms) then this is probably the best approach.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but your solution didn't work for me, when I use removeAllListeners, on('joining-room') is not fired anymore

Comment: Are you passing an event name to `removeAllListeners`? If you're not then it's likely removing listeners that you did not intend to remove.